# Could the "Made Community Wiki by ..." entry in the revision list show the actual reason?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, community-wiki, revisions-list

[As we know](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741), a post (question or answer) can be made community-wiki automatically when some conditions occur, like adding too many answers or having too much edits.

In these cases, the revision history shows an entry like this one:

> Post Made Community Wiki by errordeveloper

This conversion of [Better term for "user"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/posts/11401/revisions) to Community Wiki was triggered by an addition of the 31th answer by errordeveloper.

The revision history could show here:

> Post Made Community Wiki by the 31th answer being posted.

For too many edits (like [my answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/102197/revisions)), it could show:

> Post Made Community Wiki by the 11th edit of Paŭlo Ebermann

or

> Post Made Community Wiki by being edited by 5 different editors.

If a moderator (or the answer's owner) actively made a post community wiki, it should show this too, of course.

(Of course, the actual phrases used here can be adapted, these are just examples.)

Answer (score 9):

This is a great idea - we've never explicitly stored why a post became community wiki, but there's usually enough information in the history to infer it.

That being said, history can sometimes be a bit... flaky, so it's a best effort.  If there is a lot of missing data, we can probably fix it up.

Thanks again for the suggestion; we'll push a first draft in the next build.

Comment: This failed in [a recent Super User question](http://superuser.com/questions/623511/what-is-the-exact-use-of-a-mac-address), which for all posts shows *"Post Made Community Wiki by tigerden"*, who happened to have posted the 16th answer. I've no idea if this is a case where history is flaky, but I doubt it, as the question was only asked 8 hours earlier.

Comment: Jarrod, this also [failed here](http://superuser.com/posts/11099/revisions), showing *"Post Made Community Wiki by user234719"* (and same message for all its answers), on June 30 2013, while the question itself dates back to  July 22 2009.

Comment: And in June 2012, [it failed here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/137507/revisions).

Comment: Ah, [animuson might have a point here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208453/strange-revision-note-for-cw/208458#208458): *"the community wiki reason is calculated on the fly, not stored with the post [...] if the question was converted to wiki by having 30 answers and drops back below the 30 mark, the reason disappears and it shows the user who originally posted that 30th answer as having converted the question and its answers to community wiki"*.

Comment: Today, it failed on all (now: 5) answers [on a CW question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213769/work-is-hard-lets-color-the-walls), where in each answer the author of that very answer is shown in "Post Made Community Wiki by ..." (As usual: *just* for your information.)