# A question made CW by over 30 answers sometimes names the user responsible

Tags: bug, community-wiki, revisions-list

When a question gets 30 answers, it's automatically turned into a Community Wiki. That's not new and it's totally fine in my opinion.

Normally, it's supposed to show the following message in the revision history when the 30<sup>th</sup> answer is posted (for example, in [this revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/142099/revisions) - see Aug 11 '12 at 0:19):

> **Post Made Community Wiki** by question having more than 30 answers

It *used* to name the user who posted the 30th answer, until [this suggestion happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106569/152515) and it started showing the above message.

### The bug: it recently did not work this way

A couple of days ago I noticed weird behavior in [the revisions of the Top Bar announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/207420/revisions), where the 30<sup>th</sup> answer caused something like this to temporarily appear in the revisions:

> **Post Made Community Wiki** by [name of a particular user]

The user was not a moderator and was not the question owner. It was in fact the user who posted the 30<sup>th</sup> answer - an ordinary, plain user. This was spotted and "fixed" manually:

> [image: The revision history for the announcement. At one point, it says "Mod Removes Wiki by Jaydles," who is a moderator. Later, it says "Post Made Community Wiki by question having more than 30 answers."]

Then, when the next answer arrived about 8 hours later, it re-triggered the Community Wiki conversion which shows up with the proper notice, as you can see.

Ordinarily, the only users who can convert a post into Community Wiki themselves are diamond moderators, [as in this revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/18545/revisions). Nobody else should be able to convert a post into Community Wiki, except by posting the 30<sup>th</sup> answer, in which case they should not be named.

However, apparently, in this instance the 30<sup>th</sup> answer converted the post into Community Wiki and the user who made that post was named as having converted it into a CW post.

Was the bug fixed, or is it affecting only the first time question is turned into a CW?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd So is the bug simply that the revision history should not say "made community wiki by [author]" and instead should just say it was made community wiki by the question having >30 posts?

Comment: Very much related: [Could the “Made Community Wiki by …” entry in the revision list show the actual reason?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106569/could-the-made-community-wiki-by-entry-in-the-revision-list-show-the-actua) (See also my comments to Jarrod's answer.)

Comment: @Arjan true, but instead of asking to reopen that old feature request think it's better to report a bug in its implementation.

Comment: (Sure thing, which is exactly why I didn't vote to close `;-)`)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I did some heavy rewriting/editing on this question in hopes of making what you're reporting clearer. Please check it still makes sense and is saying what you want it to say!

Comment: @Jonath awesome job, I tried to upvote the question and was amazed it's my own! :D

Comment: CW isn't triggered by too many answers anymore. This should not be an issue now for anything except old questions. (In other words, not something that really needs to be fixed.)